# Ansible handlers include_task does not work with tags

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a problem when trying to invoke an include tasks with tags from handlers. When executing it, it ignores the tags and executes all the tasks of the playbook

services.yaml

```yaml
- name: stop service
  become: true
  systemd:
    name: httpd
    state: stopped
  tags: stop

- name: start service
  become: true
  systemd:
    name: httpd
    state: started
  tags: start
```

main.yaml

```yaml
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - name: ask stop / start
      pause:
        prompt: "please type start or stop"
        echo: yes
      register: ask
      changed_when: true
      notify: service
      tags: restarting
   
  handlers:
    - name: service
      include_tasks: services.yaml
      tags: "{{ ask.user_input }}"
```

execute

```
ansible-playbook main.yam -t restarting
```

When I run it, it launches all the tasks omitting the tag.

Answer (score 3):

There is no point to use *tags* on handlers. A handler is either notified or not. Use conditions if you want to run handlers conditionally, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat services.yaml
- debug:
    msg: stop service
  when: ask.user_input == 'stop'

- debug:
    msg: start service
  when: ask.user_input == 'start'
```

Then the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: ask stop / start
      pause:
        prompt: "please type start or stop"
        echo: true
      register: ask
      changed_when: true
      notify: service
      tags: [restarting, never]
  handlers:
    - name: service
      include_tasks: services.yaml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t restarting

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************

TASK [ask stop / start] ****************************************************
[ask stop / start]
please type start or stop:
changed: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [service] **************************************************
included: /export/examples/example-269/services.yaml for localhost

RUNNING HANDLER [debug] ****************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: start service

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************
localhost: ok=3 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=1 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

Add *never* tag to ask for the input only when *restarting* is selected.

Comment: Why, then, does Ansible not _warn_ about handlers having tags, when it ignores them? It warns about issues of a lesser significance, it seems... Sigh...

Comment: You're right. Open a feature request with [ansible-lint](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/issues).